# Question regarding python scraping in the example linked in the post

Tags: python

I was reviewing this example -[Can someone explain me in detail how this code works regarding (Using Python to Access Web Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900251/can-someone-explain-me-in-detail-how-this-code-works-regarding-using-python-to) and have a question about one of the last lines in the code where the count = 0

Could anyone please explain why it needs to be there? If possible, @chitown88 could you help for you've been involved in this thread?

```
if count == position:  #<------- and the variable to get the position
         url  = tag.get('href', None)
         print("Retrieving:" , url)
         count = 0  <----------------------------------------this line
         break
```

Thank you,

Comment: Since `count` was declared outside of the `while` loop, before breaking out of the inner `for` loop, the code resets the `count` variable to `0` for the next iteration of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
...
count = 0 # <-- Must reset this value.
...

while n < numbers:
    ...
    for tag in tags:
      ...
      if count == position:
         ...
         count = 0 # <-- Resetting this value before the next for-loop.
         break # <-- This breaks out of the for-loop, going back into the while-loop
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I understand that it's needed for the code to be able to do a fresh count after it switches to the next url. Makes sense.